# when we want to compile the solidity Contract but error occur

Tags: mocha.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! lottery2@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lottery2@1.0.0 test script.
.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abdul/.npm/_logs/2020-04-27T15_12_19_628Z-debug.log

Comment: please, take a tour to the site, and check how answers that have usefull answers are structured. You hae to provide elements so that they are ansewarable.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the mocha dependency in your project folder.